# Python Pandas install issue on AWS

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

Hi I have been trying to install Pandas for Python3.5 on AWS for the past couple of hours. I have googled and looked through a lot of posts related but still can't figure it out. Here's the error I get when I run sudo pip install pandas

```
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.20.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Running from numpy source directory.
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/setup.py:367: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    /usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning: 
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning: 
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning: 
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning: 
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning: 
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    /usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 152, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 237, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 267, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 236, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/setup.py", line 392, in <module>
        """Custom distutils command subclassed from Cython.Distutils.build_ext
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/setup.py", line 384, in setup_package
        """ % src)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 152, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 26, in run
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 165, in build_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 324, in build_extension_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 421, in generate_config_h
        tag = bdist_wheel.get_tag(self)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 47, in check_types
        setuptools_kwargs = {}
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 280, in check_types
        pjoin(ujson_python,'JSONtoObj.c'),
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-j9m4xuc4/pandas/setup.py", line 729, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 265, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 310, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 799, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 377, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 642, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 672, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 857, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1085, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1071, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 240, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 164, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 139, in resume
        compat.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/compat.py", line 65, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 152, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 237, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 267, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 236, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/setup.py", line 392, in <module>
        """Custom distutils command subclassed from Cython.Distutils.build_ext
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/setup.py", line 384, in setup_package
        """ % src)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 152, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 26, in run
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 165, in build_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 324, in build_extension_sources
      File "/tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 421, in generate_config_h
        tag = bdist_wheel.get_tag(self)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 47, in check_types
        setuptools_kwargs = {}
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 280, in check_types
        pjoin(ujson_python,'JSONtoObj.c'),
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]
     int exp (void);
         ^
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/easy_install-t1qzuvjo/numpy-1.13.1/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’ [enabled by default]
     int exp (void);
         ^
    _configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    _configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-j9m4xuc4/pandas
```

I have tried uninstalling/installing pandas, numpy.

My pip version seems to be a bit weird:

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip3 --version
pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

Comment: *SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.* Do you have `python-dev` installed?